# Unknown Exception when using .NET 4.5 and Mixed Assemblies

Tags: c++, .net, command-line-interface, mixed

I have a problem when the new .Net Framework (version 4.5) is installed. I am working on a plugin assembly that is accessed through native code. The library is build using Visual Studio 2010 and with .NET 4.0 as target plattform.

The following code snippet throws an exception in .NET 4.5 and is working fine in .NET 4.0. Any idea how to fix this issue?

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#pragma managed(push, on)

static bool ManagedTestFunction() {
    return false;
}

#pragma managed(pop)

static void CheckIfManagedUnmanagedTransitionIsPossible() 
{
    try 
    {
        ManagedTestFunction();
    }
    catch (...) 
    {
        throw misc::mwException(0, _T("The program is not working if .NET Framework 4.5 is installed. Please revert to previous version .NET 4.0!"));
    }
};
```

Best regards

Michael

Answer (score 0):

I would look at what exception was originally thrown -- that should give you a clue as to why the code does not work under .NET Framework 4.5.

Comment: Hi, 
thank you for your advice. As the catch block is in plane native code, I cannot catch any managed exception. Unfortunately, the exception through is no std::exception. Any idea what I should catch?
Michael

Comment: If there is some kind of root exception (like Exception in .NET), I would try to catch that. You might also try catching (I think) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't any root exception in native c++.

Answer (score 0):

finally I solve the problem myself. It is maybe a conceptional problem due to some optimization in .NET 4.5. Concider the following example:

```
// managed class
ref class A
{
}

// native class holding a reference to A
class B 
{
    msclr::gcroot<A^> m_refA;
};
```

When first crossing the native-managed boundary, the new .NET Framework tries to resolve all managed types that are reference in native classes independent whether they are actually used or not. At that time, it is not yet possible to subscribe to the AppDomain.ResolveAssembly event. If the framework cannot resolve a type, the crash happens.

A possible solution is modify class B such that it stores a reference to a System::Object^ instead and to cast dynamically using "cli_safe((System::Object^) m_refA)"

Best regards

Michael